# Adicionar linha de média com seaborn - python

Tags: python, histograma, graphics, seaborn

**Como incluo uma linha vertical referente à média de cada uma das classes nos histogramas, usando seaborn?**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
wine = load_wine()
features = pd.DataFrame(data=wine['data'],columns=wine['feature_names'])
df_wine = features
df_wine['target']=wine['target']
df_wine['class']=df_wine['target'].map(lambda ind: wine['target_names'][ind])



fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
title = fig.suptitle("Alcohol", fontsize=14)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.93, wspace=0.3)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xlabel("Alcohol")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency") 

g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df_wine, 
                  hue='class', 
                  palette={"class_0": "r", "class_1": "y", "class_2": "b"})

g.map(sns.distplot, 'alcohol', 
      kde=True, bins=15, ax=ax)

ax.legend(title='class')
plt.close(2)
```

[image: saída do gráfico sem a linha da média]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma função do `matplotlib` que insere uma linha vertical no gráfico, é a `.axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1, **kwargs)`, que tem a documentação [aqui](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) ou [aqui](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html).

No seu caso, basta calcular a média de cada classe e inserir no gráfico. Uma maneira de fazer isso é:

```
color_dict = {"class_0": "r", "class_1": "y", "class_2": "b"}
for target in df_wine['class'].unique():
    ax.axvline(df_wine[df_wine['class']==target]['alcohol'].mean(), 0, 1, color=color_dict[target])
```